# Edit title slide of R Markdown Slidy Presentation

Tags: r-markdown, slidy

Is there a way to edit the title slide of a R Markdown Slidy Presentation? I am able to add the header, footer, and custom css:

```
title: "Slidy Template"
author: ""
date: "June 18, 2015"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  slidy_presentation:
    css: ./styles/Slidy_Styles.css
    includes:
      after_body: ./styles/doc_suffix.html
      before_body: ./styles/header.html
```

But I can't figure out how to either add anything besides title, author, and date to the slide, or else replace the standard slidy title slide with a custom html template, like I do with the header and footer.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the part about title page in the pandoc [slidy template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.slidy), also found with `pandoc -D slidy`.

```
$if(title)$
<div class="slide titlepage">
  <h1 class="title">$title$</h1>
$if(subtitle)$
  <h1 class="subtitle">$subtitle$</h1>
$endif$
  <p class="author">
$for(author)$$author$$sep$<br/>$endfor$
  </p>
$if(date)$
  <p class="date">$date$</p>
$endif$
</div>
$endif$
```

Save the resulting file as default.slidy in your pandoc template directory :

```
$HOME/.pandoc/templates (unix)
C:\Documents And Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\pandoc\templates (windows XP)
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\pandoc\templates (windows 7)
```

Comment: Thank you! This also works with iosolides if you save the template as default.ioslides

Answer (score 0):

Rmarkdown will not remove the title slide from a slidy presentation if you do not give a title. Simply, remove the title line from the yaml setting and add the first slide to give the details as you please.

```
author: ""
date: "June 18, 2015"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  slidy_presentation:
    css: ./styles/Slidy_Styles.css
    includes:
      after_body: ./styles/doc_suffix.html
      before_body: ./styles/header.html
---
#Slidy Template

**Author**

Affiliations

Date
---
```