# add logo only on first (main) slide in ioslides RStudio

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm using ioslides (rmarkdwon) in RStudio to create the presentation from R. I would like to add the logo, but only to the first slide (main)  which renders this information:

```
---
title: "Presentation"
author: "Tom Hanks"
output: ioslides_presentation
logo: logo.jpg
---
```

I don't want the logo in the bottom-left footer of each slide. Can anyone tell me how to switch it off?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert a logo in upper right corner of R markdown pdf document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982052/insert-a-logo-in-upper-right-corner-of-r-markdown-pdf-document)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could modify the ioslide template to remove the repetition of the logo on each page. Download the template [on the rmarkdown github repository](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/3d46213d750fd4ebb83e73d0df357f081c73f49f/inst/rmd/ioslides/default.html) or find your local version on your computer. Remove the following part:

```
$if(logo)$
    slides > slide:not(.nobackground):before {
      font-size: 12pt;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 60px;
      background: url($logo$) no-repeat 0 50%;
      -webkit-background-size: 30px 30px;
      -moz-background-size: 30px 30px;
      -o-background-size: 30px 30px;
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      padding-left: 40px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 1.9;
    }
$endif$
```

Save the resulting file as `default.ioslides` in your pandoc home:

```
$HOME/.pandoc/templates (unix)
C:\Documents And Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\pandoc\templates (windows XP)
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\pandoc\templates (windows 7)
```

The `logo` linked in your yaml front matter should now only appear on the title slide.

(I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30955475/4132844))

Answer (score 0):

This is quite hacky, but you can also put html directly into your title or author elements.

```
---
title: "Presentation"
author: 'Tom Hanks<img src="logo.jpg" width="200px" height="90px" style="position: absolute; right: -200px; bottom: -50px;">'
output: ioslides_presentation
---
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make each subsequent slide background white with `data-background=#ffffff`. The logo no longer appears at the bottom left. I don't like the default gradient that shows up at the bottom of the presentation slides either so this works for me.

```
---
title: "Presentation"
author: "Tom Hanks"
output: ioslides_presentation
logo: logo.jpg
---

## First Slide Title {data-background=#ffffff}
```